# Can I mix custom policies with out of the box user flows?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a requirement that necessitates using a custom policy for my sign-in process.

However, I would like to use out-of-the-box user flows for sign-up/registration, as they are easier to configure.

Is it possible to combine custom policies and out-of-the-box user flows in this manner, with the sign-in process using a custom policy and the sign-out and registration processes using out-of-the-box user flows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - you can't mix and match as the flows use different identifiers and are not compatible e.g. if you signup with a user flow you won't be able to sign in with a custom flow.